# Left Join in query builder gives unexpected array

Tags: left-join, symfony, query-builder

Having 2 Entities Sacperson and Docs with no relation. I want to get all the Sacpersons and the related Docs if there are any. The Entities have 2 fields in common: person and act.
Not all Sacpersons have Docs. I need all Sacpersons even if they have no docs. If they have one ore more docs I want all docs.
This is my query:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('sap')
->select('sap', 'doc')
->leftjoin('AppBundle:Doc', 'doc', 'WITH', 'sap.person=doc.person AND sap.act=doc.act')
->andWhere('sap.act = :sac_id')
->setParameter('sac_id', $sac_id)
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

It gives me all the Sacpersons and the related Docs but the array looks like this:

```
array:27 [▼
  0 => Sacperson {#678 ▶}
  1 => null
  2 => Sacperson {#920 ▶}
  3 => Doc {#923 ▶}
  4 => Doc {#909 ▶}
  5 => Sacperson {#942 ▶}
  6 => null
   etc.
```

How do I get an array where each row is an object of Sacperson and Doc instead of rows for Sacpersons or Docs?
I have been up and down all related questions and according to the information found my query should be good.

Comment: Why not reconsider you design and have the "Sacperson" have a ArrayCollection of "Doc" objects? It seems like that is what you might need but I don't know your design intent. Take a look at this [Association Mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) reference.